# 7 Day Owncloud Install Ubuntu Server LTS . Mariadb uninstall/reinstall & pkg issues for Owncloud install

Tags: mariadb

Ive been installing owncloud for a little over a week.

My issue
Trying to install Owncloud, but it gave me errors with mariadb.
So i was attempting to uninstall/reinstall mariadb when i got all this.

Could someone please help???

## Edit##

```
Setting up mariadb-server-10.0 (10.0.34-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-10.0 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.0 (>= 10.0.34-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package mariadb-server-10.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-10.0
 mariadb-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
dovedescent7@ubuntuahernhome:~$ sudo apt-get update 
Hit:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease               
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease        
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Ign:6 https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04  InRelease
Hit:7 https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04  Release
Reading package lists... Done
dovedescent7@ubuntuahernhome:~$ apt-get clean
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Could not open lock file /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

EDIT###  I USED SUDO BUT AM STILL GETTING THIS ISSUE

```
dovedescent7@ubuntuahernhome:~$ sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoclean
[sudo] password for dovedescent7: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dovedescent7@ubuntuahernhome:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mariadb-server-10.0 (10.0.34-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-10.0 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.0 (>= 10.0.34-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package mariadb-server-10.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-10.0
 mariadb-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if you're trying to run `apt clean` without root permissions... If this is true, a simple fix should be just running:

`sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoclean`

Let me know if this helps...